# Multiple file creation with sorted input

Tags: java, beginner

Is there a more efficient way to create the three files and write to those files using `BufferedOutput` and `BufferedWiter` I/O? The code works, but I thought there has to be a more compact way to accomplish this.

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class SortStudent 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       //variables for processing
        Path fileOut1 = Paths.get("Honors_Students.txt");
        Path fileOut2 = Paths.get("Good_Standing.txt");
        Path fileOut3 = Paths.get("Probation_Students.txt");
        String recOut;
        String delimiter = ",";
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int QUIT = 999;

        //data class record
        Student student = new Student();

        //input.output may generate exceptions
       try
       {
            //Setup the 3 files to be used for output 
            OutputStream output1 = 
                   new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(fileOut1, CREATE));   
            OutputStream output2 = 
                   new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(fileOut2, CREATE));  
            OutputStream output3 = 
                   new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(fileOut3, CREATE));                        
            BufferedWriter writer1 = 
                   new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output1));      
            BufferedWriter writer2 = 
                   new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output2));        
            BufferedWriter writer3 = 
                   new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output3));

            BufferedWriter writer = null;

           //initial read for indefinite repetition
           System.out.print("Enter Student's ID number or 999 to quit: ");
           student.setID(input.nextInt());

           //sentinel controlled loop
           while (student.getID() != QUIT)
           {
                //get Student First Name
                System.out.print("Enter Student's First Name: ");
                student.setFirstName(input.next());

                //get Student Last Name
                System.out.print("Enter Student's Last Name: ");
                student.setLastName(input.next());

                //get Student GPA
                System.out.print("Enter Student's Grade Point Average: ");
                student.setgpa(input.nextDouble());

                //if gpa is 3.6 or> write to Honors Student
                if (student.Honors())
                    writer=writer1;

                //if gpa is >=2.0  and >3.5 write to Good Standing Student
                else if (student.Good_Standing())
                        writer=writer2;

                //if gpa is <2.0  write to Probation Student
                else if (student.Probation())
                        writer=writer3;

                //out of range 
                else
                    continue;

                //build the record
                recOut = student.getID() + delimiter
                        + student.getFirstName() + delimiter
                        + student.getLastName() + delimiter 
                        + student.getgpa();


                //write the record
                writer.write(recOut, 0, recOut.length());
                writer.newLine();


                //subsequent read for indefinite repetition
                System.out.print("Enter a Student's ID number or 999 to quit: ");
                student.setID(input.nextInt());

            }
            //close all files
            writer1.close();
            writer2.close();
            writer3.close();      
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        { 
            System.out.println("<<An exception has occurred.>> ");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());   
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Formatting

Your `if` statement block should use braces `{ ... }` to better identify the scope of each clause as a good practice. Also, you can consider renaming `setgpa(double)/getgpa()` to `setGpa(double)/getGpa()` respectively.

#### `try-with-resources`

Since Java 7, you should be using [`try-with-resouces`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for safe and efficient handling of your I/O resources:

```
private static final Path HONORS = Paths.get("Honors.txt");
private static final Path GOOD_STANDING = Paths.get("GoodStanding.txt");
private static final Path PROBATION = Paths.get("Probation.txt");
private static final String DELIMITER = ",";
private static final int QUIT = 999;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (PrintWriter honorsWriter = new PrintWriter(HONORS.toFile());
         PrintWriter goodStandingWriter = new PrintWriter(GOOD_STANDING.toFile());
         PrintWriter probationWriter = new PrintWriter(PROBATION.toFile());
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)
    ) {
        // ...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I have taken the liberty to declare your file paths as `private static final` constants outside of the `main()` method, again as a good practice. Also, I have opted to use a [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html), which is buffered, so that I can make use of its `println(String)` method.

#### Determining the student's details and ranking

You are creating only one `Student` instance, and then repopulating its details for each input. Ideally, you should be creating a new one each time, so that they can all go into a `Collection` in the future for further processing. Right now, you probably can settle for temporary variables in order to print them afterwards.

Assuming we are sticking with your approach, you can *hide* the `Student` creation within its own method, e.g. `getStudent(Scanner)`. The idea is that given a `Scanner` instance, student details can be retrieved and a `Student` instance is returned:

```
Student student = getStudent(scanner);
```

#### Joining strings with delimiter

Since Java 8, you can use [`String.join(CharSequence, CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) to easily join strings:

```
private static String toFileOutput(Student student) {
    return String.join(DELIMITER,
            Integer.toString(student.getID()),
            student.getFirstName(),
            student.getLastName(),
            student.getGpa());
}
```

#### Determining the file output

Instead of reassigning the writers to a `writer`, you should be using them directly:

```
Student student = getStudent(scanner);
while (student.getID() != QUIT) {
    String output = toFileOutput(student);
    if (student.isHonors()) {
        honorsWriter.println(output);
    } else if (student.isGoodStanding()) {
        goodStandingWriter.println(output);
    } else if (student.isProbation()) {
        probationWriter.println(output);
    }
    student = getStudent(scanner);
}
```

#### `for` vs `while`

Another way of looping through each `Student` input is to use a `for` loop, this approach is sometimes (often? always?) recommended to reduce the scope of the `student` instance:

```
for (Student student = getStudent(scanner);
     student.getID() != QUIT;
     student = getStudent(scanner)) {
    // ...
}
```

#### Shortening the process

Alternatively, you can consider [`Files.write(Path, Iterable, OpenOption)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) to expressively write (pun unintended) a line of output, the only thing to be aware of is that you will need to turn your single `String` into an `Iterable`, e.g. using `Collections.singleton(T)`.

Putting it altogether:

```
public static void main() {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        for (Student student = getStudent(scanner);
             student.getID() != QUIT;
             student = getStudent(scanner)) {
            Set<String> output = Collections.singleton(toFileOutput(student));
            if (student.isHonors()) {
                Files.write(HONORS, output, APPEND);
            } else if (student.isGoodStanding()) {
                Files.write(GOOD_STANDING, output, APPEND);
            } else if (student.isProbation()) {
                Files.write(PROBATION, output, APPEND);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do we need to provide the OpenOption.APPEND parameter for Files.write(...) ?

Comment: @oopexpert good catch! Have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should not distorte semantics. student.getID() != QUIT is semantically strange. My suggestion is to check for QUIT BEFORE creating a Student
2. You should not reuse of the Student-object for different Students. Technically this is ok but it's not object-oriented and not semantically correct either
3. Try-catch with resources is the proper approach handling File I/O Errors
4. I do not suggest to hold the files open during long user input. My way would be to have the files open when writing is neccessary and closed during user input.